# error while downloading npm packing "editly"

Tags: node.js, npm

im facing this error while downloading package named as "Editly".please help if you know how to solve this problem:

here is the link from where im downloading it
https://github.com/mifi/editly

npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/editly/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! (node:16890) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/editly/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/editly/node_modules/gl/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/editly/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/saqiburrehman/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/saqiburrehman/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/editly/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/saqiburrehman/.cache/node-gyp/16.13.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/editly/node_modules/gl',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: 1: python: not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'python commit_id.py check ..' returned exit status 127 while in angle/src/angle.gyp. while loading dependencies of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/editly/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.11.0-41-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/editly/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/editly/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: node js version is up-to-date 16.13.2. have installed all dependencies.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is very long and not formated well. Consider using a block quote to display vermbatim program outputs. Also you should provide steps that you did before getting the error message. This will help others to reproduce your problem.